# How to override Laravel Passport Routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have upgraded to Laravel 9 along with Passport v11.8

The laravel 9 documentation states you can now override Passport routes (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#overriding-routes) by adding `Passport::ignoreRoutes` to the register method of your application's AppServiceProvider and the routes defined by Passport in its routes file to your application's routes/web.php file and modify them to your liking.

I've updated my web.php file as follows:

```
Route::group([
  'as' => 'passport.',
  'prefix' => config('passport.path', 'oauth'),
  'namespace' => 'Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers',
], function () {
    
    Route::get('/clients', [
        'uses' => 'ClientController@forUser',
        'as' => 'clients.index',
    ]);

    // Other Passport routes...
});
```

However I get the following error when I view the laravel.log file:

```
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController] does not exist. {"userId":4138,"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [App\\Http\\Controllers\\Laravel\\Passport\\Http\\Controllers\\ClientController] does not exist. at C:\\wamp\\www\\laravel\\my-project\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php:891)
```

Do i have to also create the class under `App\Http\Controllers\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController`

Any advise or help appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use your own method in your own controller, you need to remove **namespace** from `Route::group`. After that you can update the **uses** property of your `Route::get('/clients)` for example by `'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\TestController@test'`.

Comment: @vins I don't want to use my own methods, i just need to update the routing

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resolve by adding `\` to:

```
'namespace' => '\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers',
```